# Trouble with file extension Association in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, file, regedit

I did a media player and now I want that the default application for mp3, wav and ogg files is my application.

I tried the following code to make that but I become an error:

```
    private static bool IsAssociated()
    {
        return Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey( "Software\\Classes\\.mp3", false ) == null;
    }

    private static void Associate()
    {
        RegistryKey FileReg = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey( "Software\\Classes\\.mp3" );
        RegistryKey AppReg = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey( "Software\\Classes\\Applications\\BeatMusicPlayer.exe" );
        RegistryKey AppAssoc = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey( "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Explorer\\FileExts\\.mp3" );

        FileReg.CreateSubKey( "DefaultIcon" ).SetValue( "", "" );
        FileReg.CreateSubKey( "PerceivedType" ).SetValue( "", "Audio" );

        AppReg.CreateSubKey( "shell\\open\\command" ).SetValue( "", "\"" + Application.ExecutablePath + "\" %1" );
        AppReg.CreateSubKey( "DefaultIcon" ).SetValue( "", "" );

        AppAssoc.CreateSubKey( "UserChoice" ).SetValue( "Progid", "Applications\\BeatMusicPlayer.exe" );
    }
```

And

```
    static void Main( string[] args )
    {
        if( !IsAssociated() )
            Associate();
    }
```

But in the line `AppAssoc.CreateSubKey( "UserChoice" ).SetValue( "Progid", "Applications\\BeatMusicPlayer.exe" );` I become the exception `System.UnauthorizedAccessException`

I tried to run the program as an administrator but nothing changes.

Kind regards

Comment: Add a permission request to your OpenSubKey: `Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("[TheSubKeyName]", Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree, System.Security.AccessControl.RegistryRights.WriteKey);`.  See [RegistryKeyPermissionCheck](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKeyPermissionCheck%29%3Bk%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework&f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: I don't want to check for permissions, I want to know how to avoid this error/Why this error ocurres.